# Selected text color and background color on WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, html, css, browser, webbrowser-control

I'm having a problem when trying to change the highlight color of selected text in WebBrowser Control.
What I'm trying to do is making the selected text not hightlighted.
I used this css.

```
<style>* ::selection{color:#000;}</style>
```

It worked with IE, but when I try with WebBrowser Control, the text is still be highlighted.
Any help would be appreciate. Thanks!

Update: I notice that the selected text color in WebBrowser Control is changed depend on color of Selected Item in Windows Color and Appearance. But I cannot make the highlight color transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `<style>*::selection{text-decoration:none;}</style>`